# How to href an Alert Box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I "href" an alert box that can be stylized? I meant to get an alert box when clicking "About", and I mean to stylize this box modifying its transparency and fonts. I have few ideas of how to do it and my tries have failed, so here I am asking for help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Documento senza titolo</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css" />
<link rel="icon" href="Senza titolo-1.ico" />
</head>

<body>

    <div id="main">

        <div id="logo">
        <a href="index.html">
        <img src="Syrenlogo.png" width="130px" height="130px" />
        </a>
        </div><!--ends logo-->

        <br/>
        <br/>

        <div id="abovenavigation">

        <ul class="container">

            <li><a href="index.html"><h1 class="Home">HOME</h1></a></li><!--
            --><li><h1 class="About">ABOUT</h1></li><!--
            --><li><h1 class="Blog">BLOG</h1></li><!--
            -->

        </ul><!--ends container--> 

        </div><!--ends upper navigation-->

          <br/>
          <br/>

        <div id="me">
        <img src="Gregory1.png" width="300px" height="300px" onclick="this.src='Gregory2.png'" onmouseover="this.src='Gregory2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Gregory1.png'"/>
        </div>

        <br/>
        <br/>

        <div id="undernavigation">

            <ul class="container">
            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Albus.Severus.Vitanza" target="_blank"><img class="facebook" src="Facebook.png" width="53px" height="50px" onclick="this.src='Facebookhov.png'" onmouseover="this.src='Facebookhov.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Facebook.png'"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/Promoetheus" target="_blank"><img class="twitter" src="Twitter.png" width="53px" height="50px" onclick="this.src='Twitterhov.png'" onmouseover="this.src='Twitterhov.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Twitter.png'" /></a></li>
            <li><a href:"mailto:gaaren03@gmail.com"><img class="mailto" src="Mailto.png" width="53px" height="50px" title="gaaren03@gmail.com" onclick="this.src='Mailtohov.png'" onmouseover="this.src='Mailtohov.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Mailto.png'" /></a></li>
            </ul>

        </div><!--ends undernavigation-->

    </div><!--ends main-->

    <div id="search">   
        <a href="#search"><img class="search" src="Search.png" height="50px" width="50px" /></a>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show your attempts and let us know what specifically went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot stylize an `alert` popup (as in the ones you make by JavaScript's `alert()`).

Perhaps what you're looking for are modal popups:

- [Foundation 5's Reveal Modal](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html)
- [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) Modal ([demo](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=modal))

Comment: Yes, it sounds pretty much what I need. Can you have this modal come up "onclick"? Like a Href let's say?

Comment: Take a look at the specific documentation for how to achieve it! In the case of Foundation's Reveal modal, you do it by attaching `data-reveal-id="yourModalID"`to the `<a>` tag, where `yourModalID` is the ID of the `<div>` of the popup.

Answer (score 0):

Use the modal dialog from bootstrap. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals